# Error when starting Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, svn, mercurial

I'm running a java project in Eclipse, and using Subversion.

When I open Eclipse, I'm getting this message about some unexpected Mercurial errors:

> There are some unexpected Mercurial errors occured.
>
> Please check the Error Log view for detailed information.
>
> . Command line: hg -y debuginstall
>
> . Command line: hg -y debuginstall
>
> . Command line: hg -y debuginstall

Since I'm not using mercurial, do you have any idea why I'm getting this message?

Comment: Have you checked the Error Log view as suggested?

Comment: I uninstalled the plugin someone had installed in the copy of eclipse I got and them this error has gone..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely to have the Mercurial plugin installed. Even though you're not actually using it it is probably trying to initialize itself without success. You can check this by choosing `Help -> Install new software...` and then the `What is already installed link`. In the `Installed software` tab you should find an entry for `MercurialEclipse`. If you do not plan to use Mercurial at all you might consider uninstalling this plugin.

Otherwise, if you have Mercurial installed on your computer and you do not want to uninstall the MercurialEclipse plugin choose `Window -> Preferences...`, expand the `Team -> Mercurial` node and check that the `Mercurial Executable:` field points to where Mercurial is installed on your system.